# Regex: Exact plus wildcard text

Tags: regex

I'm looking for regex for my auto suggest key search.

String example:

```
universal studio japan
universal
japan
```

basically if user types "universal jap" or "universal japan",
"universal studio japan" should match.

Comment: Well, `"universal studio japan"` will match `"universal studio japan"`, but why do you even need a regex?

Comment: so in the question i specified that we only have "universal" and " japan" no studio..

Comment: You don't need regex as @DeepSpace mentioned, but if you really wanted to use it, you can use `^universal studio japan$` with the `m` modifier (multiline)

Comment: @user1955934 then your question is not clear, could you please edit your question to include all relevant information and clarify what exactly your needs/expectations are?

Comment: editing my question sorry..

Comment: @user1955934 so if I understand correctly, you're looking for matches if someone types the partial sentence, but it must include at least two words from the partial? So `universal jap` matches the string `universal studio japan`, as does `universal japan`, but if a user only inputs `universal`, this should not match the string `universal studio japan`?

Comment: single word input is taken care of i think, so im looking for help with multiple word inputs

Comment: @user1955934 I do apologize, but I still don't really understand what you're looking for. If you post a list of inputs and expected outputs (for each of the inputs) and why each of the expected outputs are as they are (the why behind your question), we might be able to better provide you a "how"

Comment: @user1955934 if you're looking to match `universal`, followed by anything, followed by `japan`, you can use `\buniversal\b[ \w-]*\bjapan\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this doesn't feel like a very good question, but anyway here you go:

```
/universal .+ japan/gi    => gi for global & case insensitive
```

take a look at https://regex101.com/

Comment: this works, but it doesn't actually match "universal japan", how do i make it so that it also match "universal japan"

Comment: /universal.+japan/gi  i removed the space and it seems to be the solution, appreciate it!

Comment: solution from ctwheels's comment is better \buniversal\b.+\bjapan

Answer (score 0):

To match words, you should surround them with `\b` (word boundary). This will check to ensure there is a "word boundary", which asserts `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)` matches the position in the string.

Using something like the following will match any character between `universal` and `japan`, which may not be what you're looking for, but I'm posting it so that you (the OP) can decide which method works best for you.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/mt1S99/3)

```
\buniversal\b.*\bjap(?:an)?\b
```

This next method will only match word characters (`a-zA-Z0-9_`), hyphens `-`, or spaces between words (ensuring there is no other special character such as a dot/period `.`). Regular expressions can get complicated fast, so, assuming you now also want to match decimal points or abbreviated words, this regex will no longer be the best solution and you should use the first.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/mt1S99/2)

```
\buniversal\b[ \w-]*\bjap(?:an)?\b
```

Also, note that I changed `japan` to `jap(?:an)?` since your question specifies it should also match `jap`. Should this not be the case, simply replace the latter with the former.